# Java recognizes Jar library on desktop and doesn't recognize it on Server

Tags: java, windows, postgresql, jar, debian

I run PostgreSQLJDBC.class with jar on my desktop Windows and it shows me need result.
`java -cp .;postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar PostgreSQLJDBC`

But when I upload class file and Jar file onto server (Debian Wheezy) and run

> java -cp .:postgresql-9.3.1102.jdbc41.jar PostgreSQLJDBC

it shows me an error:

```
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mytable 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mytable
```

But I'm pretty sure that files are in this directory.
What's the problem may be?

Comment: Does postgresql-9.3.1102.jdbc41.jar exist in the directory from where you are running the java command.

Comment: Yes it exists, I checked it with  test -f postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar  && echo "File exists" || echo "doesn't exist"
 command

Comment: just do `dir postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar` and see what windows has to say?

Comment: Volume in drive C is Windows8_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 8AC1-5D75

 Directory of C:\Users\ardak\workspace\PostgreConnection\bin

12/21/2014  12:18 PM           592,322 postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar
               1 File(s)        592,322 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  894,110,150,656 bytes free

Comment: And what command you gace in `DriverManager....`

Comment: con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

Comment: and what's in `Class.forName`?

Comment: There is no class.forname

Comment: In one file I have nothing given

Answer (score 0):

The user running the java process, does it have all the permission in the directory and jar file?